# Hover effect and underline disappear with changing the background color

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a main panel in an angular project. I wanted to change the background color of it, but then my underline and hover effects disappear.

Before changing the background color:

[image]

After changing the background color to white:

[image]

I have an admin layout which looks like this:

```
<div class="main-panel">
    <app-navbar></app-navbar>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

With the css:

```
.main-panel {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

Also the following home.component, where the text is:

```
 <div><span class="highlight">Cloud Native</span>: Cloud Training, Cloud Development, Cloud Architecture, Cloud Assesment....</div>
```

And this is my css for the underlined and hovered element:

```
.highlight {
  position: relative;
}

.highlight::after {
  content: " ";
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 1px;
  height: 25%;
  background-color: #9bffb0a6;
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.highlight:hover::after {
  background-color: #80ff9b;
}
```

Comment: Here I tried with what you shared above in stackblitz.com. But I got underline when I hovered the text.

Ref: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxjs-playground-uytkcj?file=app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by the negative `z-index`. Remove the property or set it to zero.

By setting this negative `z-index`, you move the `::after` pseudo element behind `.main-panel` and since you explicitly set background color to the `.main-panel`, the pseudo element is always invisible.